# How to Automate Pasting Across Sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a process which is both time-consuming and prone to human error.

For example, this is the data sheet:
[image: data sheet]

Each day the date in A1 changes, and so does the data in the table. Each category (hard candy, lolipop, gumdrops) has it's own reference sheet.

The reference sheets look like this:

Hard Candy Reference Sheet:
[image: hard candy sheet]

Lolipops Reference Sheet:
[image: lolipop sheet]

Gumdops Reference Sheet:
[image: gumdrops sheet]

(The green bar being the current day)

Essentially across several sheets for individual items, there are tables that update through the use of lookups, in reference to a main data sheet which is updated daily. Because the main sheet is updated daily, the data must be locked all other sheets via copy and special pasting.

To avoid having to manually copy and paste each time the data is updated, how do I automate the copy and pasting process based on the date given in the daily updating sheet?

Comment: What have you done to try and solve the problem? What code have you developed and how does the output differ from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide not a full answer - pseudo-code & english mixed

```
Dim DayBk as WorkBook, DaySht as Worksheet, xBk as WorkBook

Set DayBk = ThisWorkBook  ' Presuming this code is added to the edited daily workbook
Set DaySht = DayBk.ActiveSheet ' Presuming the ActiveSheet is where the Daily data is stored
For Each Row in DaySht.UsedRange.Rows ' or use a specific range
 .. if Row is 3 (Hard Candy) then
       Set xBk = Workbooks.Open("Path to Candy WorkBook")
    End If
 .. if Row is 4 (Lollipops) then
       Set xBk = Workbooks.Open("Path to Lollipops WorkBook")
    End If
 .. if Row is 5 (GumDrops) then
       Set xBk = Workbooks.Open("Path to GumDrops WorkBook")
    End If
 .. For xCol = 2 to 8  ' 2 = B 8 = H
       xVal = xCel.Offset(0,xCol-1)
       ' Now xVal has a Cell Value from the Daily Sheet
       ' You need to figure out where to put it in the Long Term Storage Workbook
       xBk.ActiveSheet.Range(???,???).Value = xVal
    Next xCol
Next Row
```

There's still plenty for you to do there - but it's a start

Comment: Thanks !! going to keep looking for the rest.